# Multiple credit cards with Apple ID

Tags: itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, apple-id

Is it possible to use multiple credit cards with your Apple ID and switch between them?

This is a common option with most online merchants, so I don't see why Apple wouldn't have this as well. For me the issue is that I have a private credit card I use for buying apps, music, etc. and a company credit card for paying for stuff like iCloud Storage. I don't want to manually have to update my credit card info each time I need to make a purchase with the company card.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm having the pay with my personal account then claim the money back from the business as an expense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to switch cards with your Apple ID. The only option is to create a new account with a different card.

Only with Apple Pay can you switch cards when making **physical** purchases.

Comment: I really don't want to be using multiple ID's. Would it even work? If I buy iCloud Storage with one account could I use it with another? Perhaps through Family Sharing, but I really don't want to bother.

Comment: You can not use your iCloud storage with another one unless you use / purchase Family Sharing .

Also, why don't you use buy a giftcard and make a special giftcard account for it?

Comment: Well, making a giftcard account wouldn't solve my issue since I want to avoid having multiple accounts.